# Suppress [Table x about here] in only one table

Tags: endfloat

Suppose I have the following article which I use `endfloat` package to push tables to the end. My question is; is there any way to suppress the [Table 2 about here] for table 2 and keep it for other table(s)?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nolists, tabhead, fighead]{endfloat}
\begin{document}

\section{Section} This is the start of a section:

\begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{Table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
    \hline 
    Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{Table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline 
        Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
        \hline 
        Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine `\floatplace` within an extra group around the table, so this redefinition is only valid for this particular figure or table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nolists, tabhead, fighead]{endfloat}
\begin{document}

\section{Section} This is the start of a section:

\begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{Table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
    \hline 
    Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\floatplace[1]{}
\begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{Table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline 
        Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
        \hline 
        Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Usually doing things like that is a bad idea since the floating environment will float out of the extra group. But when using the endfloat package the floating environments in the text are not floating anymore, instead they are delayed by being written to an extra file. So when using the endfloat package, putting `figure` or `table` in an extra group (to keep redefinitions local) is totally fine.